# How to make slideshow background image in asp.net using vb 2010

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to make slideshow background image in asp.net using vb 2010?? can anyone help me please?? I am getting crazy searching for this one and unluckily I can't find it..! Please help me..! Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to use ASP.Net [AJAX SlideShow Extender control](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-AJAX-SlideShow-Extender-control-Tutorial-with-Example.aspx) ?

Comment: Yeah..! I did the slideshow but it is only in image tool and I can't drop Items inside it. All I want to do is slideshow for form background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use CSS3 it may help you. You can get help [at this link](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/)

@YeahItsMe for your question, I am putting here also, In visual studio you need extension to get intellisense [here you can get extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a15c3ce9-f58f-42b7-8668-53f6cdc2cd83). Only need is that you have installed Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1

Comment: @YeahItsMe actually visual studio and asp.net supports css3, only need to check whether your browser support it or not?

Comment: Oh ok. This is what happens on my program. The first image did that fade in and fade out but after that the next image doesn't show. I am using google chrome browser by the way.

Comment: @YeahItsMe please check path of images in css files are correct or not?

Comment: Yeah. Thank you so much I did it and it is so cool. Thank you so much! @Yog :)